# Is it possible to HTML5 Canvas draw as below figure in shorter time?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas, coffeescript

[image: スクリーンショット 2013-04-03 18.08.17]

I want to draw **the figure of blend of electric field**, but the below code takes 4 second in Google Chrome browser.

I want to use this figure in my friend physics teacher's class, but there are **only IE8 machines** in his school's computer room.

I want to let students **put freely the point charge** and watch the figure.

Is it possible to draw below figure **in shorter time?**

```
canvas = $('canvas')[0]
context = canvas.getContext "2d"
height = canvas.height
width = canvas.width

imagedata = context.createImageData 1, 1
imagedata.width = 1
imagedata.height = 1
imagedata.data[0] = 0
imagedata.data[1] = 0
imagedata.data[2] = 0
imagedata.data[3] = 256

for w in [0...width]
  for h in [0...height]
    C = 150
    r1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(200 - w, 2) + Math.pow(240 - h, 2))
    v1 = C / r1 # * Math.pow 1.001, -r
    r2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(500 - w, 2) + Math.pow(240 - h, 2))
    v2 = C / 2 / r2 # * Math.pow 1.001, -r
    v = v1 + v2
    if 5 < v and v < 6
      context.putImageData imagedata, w, h
    else if 3 < v and v < 4
      context.putImageData imagedata, w, h
    else if 1 < v and v < 2
      context.putImageData imagedata, w, h
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a library designed to do this kind of thing.

I would take a look at http://www.nickdiakopoulos.com/2012/05/14/visualization-performance-in-the-browser/

It's a pretty good write-up about different options for rending things like this and the performance trade offs between svg and canvas.